# PHP check if visitor liked my FB page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I am making a website, where I ll be keeping a download button, the download will be only available when the visitor will click the like my FB Fanpage. This should detect whether the user already liked it or its the first time.

I googled a lot, but didn't found exact solution to my query.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: where is the button located? This is quite simple on a Facebook Page tab (just use `$_REQUEST['signed_request']`), not so simple otherwise

Comment: You need to be able to identify the user, so the only way you can do this is via a request from Facebook ($_POST['signed_request'] -> decode etc), or by using the SDK to allow users to login to your site first.

Comment: @scibuff no its not on facebook, it will be on my php website

Comment: @IngmarBoddington how do I detect on a php website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FB.Event.subscribe method:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status: true,
    cookie: true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    $("#downloadlink").show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put an onclick event on the div tag surrounding the code for the FB like.  The callback function for the onclick event could then make visible (the easiest way to do this would be to use jQuery) the div tag containing the download link.

For example

```
<div id="fblike"> 
<!-- fb code -->
</div>

<div id="downloadlink">
<!-- download link here -->
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$("#downloadlink").hide();
$("#fblike").click(function() {
   $("#downloadlink").show();
});
```

Comment: I want to detect whether the user liked my page? what will the right script to do that

Answer (score 0):

If they're logged in to your site, you could intercept the click like so:

1) Give your like button an id, such as `id="likey"`

2) Use a function like this

```
$("#likey").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation    = this.href;
    //insert ajax call that records information in database
    window.location = linkLocation;
});
```

Comment: argh, msgmash beat me to it, but my way would record it so that if they come back to the site in the future, you can still show the button without them having to click "like" again

Comment: My exact question is how do I query to facebook whether the current visitor is logged in or not? if yes then whether he liked my page or not

this is my main problem, how do I solve it?